# Best PDF converter for general formats

Tags: document-converter, pdf, third-party-software, asp.net

In our SharePoint project we are looking for a third party .dll which is able to convert different file formats into PDF as follows.

.doc,.docx to PDF
.xls,.xlsx to PDF
.ppt,.pptx to PDF
HTML to PDF
Images(.jpg,.jpeg,.tiff,.png and others) to PDF
.MPP to PDF
Merging of PDF files.

Please suggest some products, mentioning whether they are commercial, open source/free/Closed source dlls. Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

I have evaluated a lot of paid solutions, as the open ones were not flexible enough or did not parse HTML correctly. The best solution I could find was Aspose.

It's not a cheap component, but does the work pretty well.

http://www.aspose.com (paid)

Answer (score 3):

I have repeated my answer to the [same question on StackOverflow below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163654/best-pdf-converter-for-general-formats/5164789#5164789).

> Shameless plug, as I worked on this
>   product, but try the [PDF Conversion
>   Services](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-Services/summary.aspx). Scalable, reliable,
>   optimised for server use, adds new
>   formats all the time ([see new DXF and
>   DWG support](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2011/02/converting-autocad-dxf-dwg-files-using.html)), supports
>   watermarking, PDF Security etc. Has a
>   web services based interface, so works
>   well with C#, Java and many other
>   platforms.
>
> [Code sample here](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/converting-office-files-to-pdf-format.html).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what version of SharePoint you are using, but if it's Office 365, you can use Microsoft Graph to convert your docs to PDF.  This api was designed specifically for that purpose:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/examples/document-conversion

Answer (score 0):

Many small APIs are available on internet for the conversion.  In my pc I use mac pdf converter it can easily coverts image based file formats to text base formats this serves best to tech users. An option batch conversion is also available in this it can convert 50 files in a time.

Comment: Please note that in general we require disclosure of any affiliation with  products or websites - I think you sort of did this by choice of username, but it would be better if you mention it in the answer. Please see [May I promote products or websites I  am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I know of two **Commercial** products that are now available. (I am not affiliated with either.)

[Nintex Workflow](https://www.nintex.com/) can convert Office documents and images to PDF's. It works but requires a significant investment (Nintex ain't cheap, and document generation runs on a quota system that is priced separately from Nintex itself.)

[HarePoint](https://www.harepoint.com/Products/HarePointWorkflowExtensions/Document-Conversion-SharePoint-Workflow-Action.aspx)'s SharePoint Workflow Extensions also include an action for converting images to PDF. I haven't tried it extensively myself, but I think it covers more image formats than Nintex.